# I have a capacitor across a full-bridge rectifier and a AC currrent source. I am not able to understand why the input is a square wave?

Tags: capacitor, current-source, full-bridge

You can see the circuit below. I don't have a lot of experience with AC current sources. Hence the confusion.

[image]

Comment: I would suggest using a voltage that at least brings diodes to conduction (2mV isn't enough, go with 2V at least) and referring the GND point to the capacitor's negative terminal, instead of one leg of the generator

Answer (score 2):

The bridge rectifier input will **not** conduct current until the supply voltage at its input terminals rises above the charged capacitor voltage hence, an AC current source at the input inevitably generates a square wave voltage so that current can flow as demanded by the AC current source.

Just think what a current source **must do** when trying to pass a nano amp into an open circuit.